# C++: use a pure virtual function in a non-virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

I'm trying to make a base class that defines the interfaces for all derived classes.

I'd like to have a function that allows one to read a config file for that class, which is working out pretty smooth using `boost::property_tree`. Let's call this function `readConfig`.
This would have to be defined in each derived class, so I made it pure virtual.

I would like to overload the `readConfig` function in the base class where every overloaded function in the base class eventually calls the pure virtual form, e.g.:

```
class Base
{
    // ...
    void readConfig(string, string);                                 // read config from file
    virtual void readConfig(boost::property_tree::ptree, string) =0; // read config from ptree
}

void Base::readConfig(string filename, string entry)
{
     boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
     read_xml(filename, pt);
     readConfig(pt, entry);       // <= Calling pure virtual function!
}
```

Basically the string version is just a quick wrapper for the pure virtual form. When I compile this, I get an error:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from std::string to boost::property_tree::ptree`
```

So it seems, the nonvirtual function (from `Base`) is not recognized as being available. I checked that my derived class definition is ok:

```
class Deriv : public Base
{
    // ...
    void readConfig(boost::property_tree::ptree, string); // implement virtual, error is on this line
}

void Deriv::readConfig( boost::property_tree::ptree pt, string entry)
{
    //...
}
```

note that I omitted a lot of `const`-correctnes, pass by reference etc. to make the code a bit more readable.

What can I do to fix this? Is using a pure virtual member-function in a non-virtual function a good idea?

Comment: `Deriv.h`, the line where I declare the function.

Comment: You wouldn't actually *call* the pure virual function in a correctly written program. Rather, you would call the corresponding most-derived override, of which there is at least one.

Comment: Does your program actually crash saying "pure virtual function called"?

Comment: @KerrekSB no it only nags about conversions

Comment: where does the compiler error actually occur? Of course, you cannot expect to get `Base:readConfig(string, string)` from within `Derived`, *unless* you explicitly call it as `Base::readConfig()`, or you add `using Base::readConfig;` to `Derived`.

Comment: please show code that actually produces the error occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the FAQ item titled "What's the meaning of, Warning: Derived::f(char) hides Base::f(double)?" available at numerous mirrors of the FAQ, including the original [English version of the FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/new/hiding-rule.html).

It is often a good idea to check the FAQ before posting.

It is quite possible that you will also find helpful (although not for the immediate problem) the FAQ item titled "Okay, but is there a way to simulate that behavior as if dynamic binding worked on the this object within my base class's constructor?", plus that if that becomes relevant, then you might also be interested in reading [my blog article about the DBDI problem](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/how-to-avoid-post-construction-by-using-parts-factories/).

Comment: wow that's it.. another afternoon wasted! Strange they don't teach that in class... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I find this is one of the trickiest issues with inheritance. One method to avoid it is to only inherit from a `private` base and declare members wanted in the `public` interface via `using` (which in turn allows to declare overloaded members with just one declaration).

Answer (score 2):

Obvious typo is obvious:

```
virtual void readConfug
```

instead of

```
virtual void readConfig
```

Also, what you're implementing is called **template method pattern**, FYI.

Comment: oops that was a typo in putting it up on stackoverflow. Yes, I knew it would be a design pattern!

Comment: @romeovs I don't see any other problem with the code. Can you reproduce a minimal example that exibits the problem - this compiles.

Comment: I suspected as much.. the problem must be deeper, probably some pointer screwup. I'd like to put it up but the problem is there is another pure virtual class between `Base` and `Deriv`. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Here's what I did now: I renamed the pure virtual function to something else (`readConfigS`). Everything works well like that. Does this clarify the problem?

Comment: -1 not relevant to the problem, should just have been a comment

Comment: @romeovs: yes, it clarifies it, but the problem was already obvious. see my answer.